# Why is a useEffect return function running before the previous function call?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

If I navigate to the Slider component, the logs will show (back to back):

1. `i init`
2. `i destroyed`

If I navigate away from component, i see no logs. I thought I would see "i destroyed". I thought that when I navigate to component I would only see:

`i init` (when component mounts)

and when I leave I would see:

`i destroyed` (when component unmounts)

Can anyone explain what I am missing?

SliderStore.ts

```
  . . .
 
  @action.bound
  async init() {
    console.log('i init')

    if (this.slides?.length === 0) {
      await this.fetchSlides()
      this.play()
    }
  }

  @action.bound
  destroy() {
    console.log('i destroyed')
    window.clearInterval(this.iid)
  }

  . . .
```

Inside component that calls store Slider.tsx

```
  const [store] = useState(() => new SliderStore())
  useEffect(() => {
    store.init()
    return store.destroy()
  }, [])
```

Comment: You are calling destroy right away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel said, you should be returning a cleanup function, but you are calling it right away.

It should be this:

```
return () => store.destroy()
```

There's also no need to call `this.setSlides([])` in destroy because the component no longer exists (is unmounted) because of the way the effect is written (without dependencies).

Comment: Makes sense, just like you have to wrap your click handlers in an arrow function to keep them from getting executed right away, thanks. Do all the store instances get garbage collected effectively? If I was going to navigate to and from the component many times it is creating instances, but not destroying them?

Comment: A store instance gets created every time the component gets mounted and it’s eligible for GC whenever the component is unmounted - even without call destroy, because the instance created on mount no longer has references to it after the component is unmounted. Why are you calling destroy anyway?

Comment: Makes sense, I am calling it to clear the setInterval that gets kicked off in the instance. I believe that it is best practice to clearInterval in order for the instance to be garbage collected?

Comment: @user3146945 - sure, if you've got a timer going, that's a valid reason to call `destroy`. The timer wasn't in your original question so it wasn't clear why it was being called, but that makes sense.